# self в Django когда использовать

Tags: django

Подскажите, пожалуйста. В каких случаях в DJANGO нужно использовать self? Например, когда мы проверяем валидность формы form_valid, то для user=form.save() не используем self. Т.е. НЕ прописываем так self.user = form.save(). Почему так?

И вообще, когда создаются запросы от пользователей, то для Класса представления создаются его экземпляры (экземпляры класса) для каждого запроса?

Точнее, хотел понять, почему при одновременных запросах, эта переменная user присваивается правильно (т.е. для каждого пользователя (запроса) отдельно)? Так же и с функциями представлениями

Comment: Я вижу тут два вопроса, и первый, про self, сформулирован очень не конкретно. На второй вопрос короткий ответ - да

Comment: Вам нужно почитать про ООП, как мне кажется. Если вы напишите `self.user = form.save()` это будет значить, что вы хотите атрибуту `user` *текущего* класса назначить результат метода ` form.save()`. Что-то мне подсказывает, что ни у вашего класса, ни у его родителя нет такого атрибута, поэтому вы результат метода присваиваете обычной переменной.

Comment: @Александр Точнее, я хотел понять, почему при одновременных запросах, эта переменная user присваивается правильно (т.е. для каждого пользователя (запроса) отдельно)? Так же и с функциями представлениями

Comment: @Dmitry Тут вопрос в другом. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, мой комментарий Александру. Возможно, там я точнее выразился